# cv2 circle valueError

Tags: python, opencv

guys

I tried the module. It works well, but sometimes it didn't cut the image corretly.

The code is

```
hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    hsv_img[:, :, 1] = 255
    hsv_img[:, :, 2] = 255
    bgr_img = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray_img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, gray_img.shape[0] / 8, param1=100, param2=30, minRadius=18, maxRadius=30)
    temp_list = []
    img_index = 1
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
        for (x, y, r) in circles:

            cropped = gray_img[max(0, int(y - 60 / 2)):int(y + 60 / 2), max(0, int(x - 60 / 2)):int(x + 60 / 2)].astype(np.float32)

            temp_list.append((cropped, (x, y)))
            img_index += 1

    temp_list = sorted(temp_list, key= lambda x: x[1][0])
    return_list = []
    for image in temp_list:
        return_list.append(image[0])

    return return_list

def images2tensor(self, img_list):
    """
    Creates a tf compliant tensor by stacking images in img_list
    :param img_list:
    :return: np.array of shape [1, 60, 60, 1]
    """
    return np.vstack([np.reshape(x, [1, 60, 60, 1]) for x in img_list])
```

And returns ValueError,

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3480 into shape (1,60,60,1)

What should i have to do?

Comment: What's the image? Share a sample one.

Comment: I thought it 1x60x60x1 can handle until 3600. can you tell me why is 1200? @EdekiOkoh

Comment: You're right, mistake on my part. I'll change it but the error still stands. The new dimensions are not the same so you cannot reshape it

Comment: 1x60x60x1 != 3480 so you are unable to reshape it like that. You need to ensure the dimensions you are reshaping is equal to the size of the array. You should preprocess the image to always have a size of 3600. It's not about what it can handle up until. They have to be the same or python doesn't know what to do with the extra values. You can't just prepend values or you will be changing the actually array.

Comment: Umm very difficult, need to struggle more for this problem. Thank you for your answer @EdekiOkoh